# Using CTE function for insert into statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to do this:

```
with
  function add_fnc(p_id number) return number
  is
  begin
    return p_id + 1; 
  end;
insert into temp_table
(
select add_fnc(1) from dual
);
```

But it shows compilation error:

> ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword

Is there a way to use CTE function with insert statement?

Comment: `create or replace function add_fnc(p_id number) return number ... ` then `insert into temp_table ...`

Comment: You don't wrap your query in brackets when trying to write an `INSERT ... SELECT ...` statement. You use brackets after the `VALUES` clause but you're trying to use the alternative form.

Comment: @GordonLinoff. Oracle supports, but not with insert statement

Comment: What is your Oracle version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
create table demo (col1 int);

insert /*+ with_plsql */ into demo (col1)
with
    function add_one(p_id number) return number
    as
    begin
        return p_id + 1; 
    end;
select add_one(rownum) 
from dual
/
```

https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/with-clause-enhancements-12cr1

Some tools may not handle this syntax. It worked for me in SQL*Plus 12.1 (when terminated by the slash character, as for PL/SQL code) but failed in PL/SQL Developer 12.0.7 (Oracle 12.1).